# Change in Instance Variable in the method don't reflecting change in original instance variable

Tags: ios, swift

I'm Building an application in which I am fetching the data through server. I'm using Alamofire for that purpose. I have function named `handleRequest(json: JSON)` who takes the response and assign the data array or json data to instance variable.

```
// Instance Variable .   

var perm = JSON()

// Network

Alamofire.request(url, method: method , parameters: params ,encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        switch(response.result){
        case .success(_):

            let result = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.handleRequest(data: result)

            break

        case .failure(_):


            break
        }

    }    

// Request Handling

func handleRequest(data: JSON){

    perm = JSON(data["permissions"])
    print(perm)

}
```

Every Thing is fine with `handleRequest(json: JSON)` function the `perm` variable printing as expected but not in other functions.

What I expect is that instance variable `var perm = JSON()` should reflect change in other function which is not happening.

Comment: The request takes _time_. If you access `perm` before you get the response, you obviously won't get a new value.

Answer (score 0):

The perm variable will always show same data always i.e.
If you are accessing perm before `self.handleRequest(data: result)` is called, you will get *Empty json* 
This is because this variable is set in closure and that will be executed once successful API response is received.

```
printPerm()

Alamofire.request(url, method: method , parameters: params ,encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        switch(response.result){
        case .success(_):
            let result = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.handleRequest(data: result)
            break
        }

    }    

func handleRequest(data: JSON){

    perm = JSON(data["permissions"])
    print(perm) //API Json data

}

func printPerm() {
    print(perm) //Empty Json

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I've actually not mention that Iam Making request inside the function  `makeRequest()`  and calling it before printing `perm` inside `ViewDidLoad()` function .